# Mobile view zoomed in

Tags: html, css, mobile

I developed a site for a project with a few videos etc. The web browser based version is fine but mobile is zoomed in and needs pinched and zoomed out to get it correct. Whats the method to get that correct on load? I'm guessing some @media query.

I have this in my head

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport' />

    <title>ReBreak News</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css"></script>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="fontawesome.js"></script>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
```

and my global.css

```
:root {
  --gradient: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 100%);
  --light: #fff;
  --grey: #f8f9fa;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.main-bgcolor {
  background-image: var(--gradient);

}
.main-bgcolor2 {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.light-color {
  color: var(--light) !important;
}
.grey-bgcolor {
  background: var(--grey);
}
.company_brand {
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.section-body {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.h1{

  color: blueviolet;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste the HTML and CSS code, please.

Comment: I've updated my post. Trouble is that its component based so there is more code in a few components. I added the index.html though,